# 400MB of csv data into mysql in under 2 hours

Tags: mysql, csv

I need to import 400MB of data into a mysql table from 10 different .txt files loosely formatted in a csv manner. I have 4 hours tops to do it.

Is this *AT ALL* possible?

Is it better to chop the files into smaller files?

Is it better to upload them all simultaneously or to upload them sequentialy?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I currently uploaded some of the files to the server, and am trying to use the "load infile" from phpmyadmin to achieve the import, using the following syntax & parameters:

```
load data infile 'http://example.com/datafile.csv' replace into table database.table fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by ';' (`id`,`status`);
```

It throws an `Access denied` error, was wondering if I could achieve this through a php file instead, as mentioned [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14514/best-way-to-import-500mb-csv-file-into-mysql-database#comment13496_14515).

Thanks again

**FINAL EDIT**
(or *My Rookie Mistakes*)

In the end, it could be done. Easily.
Paranoia was winning the war in my mind as I wrote this, due to a time limit I thought impossible. I wasn't reading the right things, paying attention to nothing else but the pressure.

The first mistake, an easy one to make and solve, was keeping the indexes while trying to import that first batch of data. It was pointed out in the comments, and I read it in many other places, but I dismissed it as unimportant; it wouldn't change a thing. Well, it definitely does.

Still, the BIG mistake was using `LOAD FILE` on a table running on the InnoDB engine. Suddenly I run into a post somewhere which's link I've lost that proclaimed that the command wouldn't perform well in InnoDB tables, giving errors such as `Lock wait` and the likes.

I'm guessing this should probably be declared as a duplicate for some InnoDB vs MyISAM question (if somewhat related), or someone could perhaps provide a more elaborate answer explaining what I only mention and know superficially, and I'd gladly select it as the correct answer (B-B-BONUS points for adding relative size of index compared to table data or something of the like).

Thanks to all those who where involved.

PS: I've replaced HeidiSQL with SQLyog since I read the recommendation on the comments and later answer, it's pretty decent and a bit faster/lighter. If I can overcome the SQLServer-y interface I might keep it as my default db manager.

Comment: It is certainly possible, but you'd have to try it on your system to find out. Go with the simplest case first, combine all files into 1 file, load that, then go from there.

Comment: It will be fast if your remove indexes and foreign key references if any for the field and table which you are inserting from CSV to MySQL database.
Once the migration is completed, you can reapply the indexes and foreign key references.

Comment: @projolovsky use mysql workbench software to connect to your db, then query your tables and export them as csv.

Comment: thanks for all the replies, really needed to at least hear something from someone, i'm pretty burned out... I'll update with the current method I'm trying out to see if someone can lend a hand

Comment: Single disk drives fairly routinely achieve write rates well above 10MB/second. What makes you think that 100MB/hour will be hard? It all depends on you being efficient with resources and constructing your table and indexes appropriately.

Comment: Also, 400mb is milli-bits. If you mean Mega, use a capital M, and if you mean Bytes, use a capital B.

Comment: @cliffordheath fair point